# How do you start another rails instance in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, paperclip

**Short Version**

How do you programmaticly start a rails server in cucumber (or other testing frameworks), and wait until it running

**Longer Version**

I am working on a project in which clients embeds some code on their website that will generate some functionality based on configuration on our website (i.e [disqus](http://disqus.com/))

I would like like to create a cucumber test that would test that feature. Something like the following:

```
  Scenario: Basic utilization
    Given I have a rails application
    And I save the following as "app/views/users/index.htmlerb"
    """
    <my code snipit here>
    """
    When I visit /users
    Then I should see my expected behavior
```

I got inspiration from this from thoughtbot's paperclip tests:

- [Basic Features](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/features/basic.feature)
- [Rails Steps](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/features/step_definitions/rails_steps.rb)

My issue I had emulating this is that i am running a Rails 3 app, and the paperclip test are based on 2.3.8

In particular I get stuck on the following step:

```
When %r{the rails application is running} do
  Dir.chdir(CUC_RAILS_ROOT) do
    require "config/environment"
    require "capybara/rails"
  end
end
```

They use that to start the application.  But that no longer works on Rails 3.

What is the rails 3 equivalent to starting a Rails app programmaticaly, AND to wait until the app is running.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have a need to do something similar.

Comment: Not yet, try upticking the question to see if that makes get any more attention

Comment: Are your existing cucumber features already testing a rails server, or are they testing some other command line utility?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, check out [guard-cucumber](https://github.com/guard/guard-cucumber).  I use it in combination with [guard-spork](https://github.com/guard/guard-spork) to speed up testing.